# Modifying variables names after restoring from checkpoint in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

let's say I have two models with different configurations. I train and checkpoint them.

```
def train_and_save_model_using_config1():
    ...


def train_and_save_model_using_config2():
    ...
```

I'd like to load these models in the same session so I can use them at the same time. The variable names are mostly the same for the above two models, so to avoid name mangling, I add a name scope for each model.

```
with tf.variable_scope("config1"):
    m1 = load_model_from_ckpt_with_config1()

with tf.variable_scope("config2"):
    m2 = load_model_from_ckpt_with_config2()
```

To restore from the checkpoint for `config1`, I collect the variables and variable names but want to rename with the proper scope.

```
path = get_path_of_config1()
var_names = tf.contrib.framework.list_variables(path)
vars = {}
for name, shape in var_names:
    var = tf.contrib.framework.load_variable(path, name)
    vars["config1/" + name] = var

saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=vars)
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(path))
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables. Not a variable: Tensor("Const:0", shape=(128, 14987), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `vars` dict in `saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=vars)` must be a dict whose value is the reference to the **tf.Variable** of current graph in current session.
But in your case `var = tf.contrib.framework.load_variable(path, name)`, the problem is that `var` is **numpy.ndarray**